# Is incremental backup in couchdb possible?

Tags: couchdb-2.0

As I'm about to implement it myself, I'm curious to know how people handle
incremental backups for their DB's.

The straight-forward way, as I see it, is to shutdown couch and use a tool
like rsync or duplicity to backup db files. It should do the job well, and
as an added bonus, it could also be used to backup views.

Does anyone know if a similar backup could be done while the couch is still
on (and the db is being updated)?

Does anyone do incremental backups in couchdb2.0?

Comment: Of course it's possible. How to safely accomplish it is another question. Unfortunately, tool recommendations are off-topic here, so probably the best we can offer here is whether CouchDB *natively* supports it, and that answer is no. However, it does support replication, which may accomplish some of the same goals.

Comment: Also note that rsync does _not_ do incremental backup. I'm not sure if you were under the impression that it does, based on your mentioning it.

Comment: Thanks  Flimzy, no I didn't meant rsync to be an incremental :) ,  so yes , replication is the only I got to know  natively  available  in couchDB , however it too not an incremental backup but a replica CouchDB which keep the two dBs in sych (kind of  back-up dB) .. so probably thats the only option for now I could think

Answer (score 1):

For incremental backup, you can query the changes feed of a database using the "since" parameter, passing the latest revision from your last backup and then copy only the changes into a new database on the same or different server.  AFAIK, there is no "since" parameter for replication, so you will need to roll your own framework for this.